# REST and content-type

Tags: php, rest

I have a question is it possible to detect content type of request, I'm building REST service and tried `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` but I get undefined index error. I need this to determine with content type I should accept and which to be rejected.

Comment: Well client sends requests to webservice server to write something in DB, it can be done by 2 methods one as html form and that's easy cause method is known and I can define it, but second is file that can be json or xml content.

Comment: You can always do conditional code like, by checking with isset($_GET), if you want to have multiple request method

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for request type - `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` - it's `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`.

From your question I can't actually determine if you're talking about request type of something else.

Edit.

`Content-type` header is usually NOT sent in request. It's not mandatory in HTTP protocol. And even if it is sent, you can't rely on it - just like on any other data that comes from user. It can be fake.

Anyway you can get all request headers with `getallheaders()` PHP function.

http://php.net/getallheaders

Comment: Rather 'application/json', 'text/json' or 'application/xml', 'text/xml' stuff

Answer (score 0):

what I interpreted is that you want to respond HTTP status code `4XX` for request which are not acceptable, Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301594/rest-web-service-acceptable-http-response-content-type-when-responding-with-sta) question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [headers_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php).

**Example:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$headers = headers_list();

var_dump($headers);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.5"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Content-Type: application/json"
}
```